# A question about a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the PDE $$u_x-6u_y=u$$ by the method of characteristic curves.

Cauchy data  is $u(x,y)=e^x$ on the line $y=-6x+2$.

I found the characteristics as $c_1=6x+y$ and $c_2=ue^{-x}$ and when I apply $c_2=f(c_1)$, I get $f(2)=1.$

I can' t finish the rest of the question...

Comment: The characteristic curves $y=-6x+c$ are parallel with the line on which initial data is given, in which case we are not able to generate a unique solution from the initial data.

Comment: It has infinitely many solutions. Every function $f$ for wich $f(2)=1$ satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Could you offer some texts about the question? I will study from it.

Comment: I don' t exactly understand, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

General solution of equation is

$$u=f(6x+y)e^x$$

From Cauchy data we get
$$f(2)e^x=e^x$$
or
$$f(2)=1$$

Then solution of our problem is $u=f(6x+y)e^x$, where $f(x)$ is any function satisfying the condition $f(2)=1$.